# IE7 & 8 throwing errors with jQuery's .slice

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, slice

The following code works great on other browsers, but on IE7 & 8 it complains about it:

```
    var divs = $(".paginate-boxes li");
        for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i+=9) {
          divs.slice(i, i+9).wrapAll("<li class='slide-portfolio'><ul></ul></li>");
        }
```

The code that it's working on is a long list of `li`s like so:

```
                        <li>
                                <!--Fade-->
                                <div class="mosaic-block fade">
                                    <a href="http://www.example.com/destination/" class="mosaic-overlay">
                                        <object class="details">

                                            <h4>Destination Page</h4>
                                            <p>
                                                                                                </p>
                                        </object>
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="mosaic-backdrop"><img width="296" height="175" src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/this_thumb.jpg" class="attachment-portfolio-image wp-post-image" alt="this_thumb" title="This image" /></div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
```

Using the Dev tools in IE9 (in 8 mode), I found that it complains when it gets to the `.slice` bit of the code, referencing this bit of jQuery (v.1.7.2)

```
// IE6-8 fail to clone children inside object elements that use
// the proprietary classid attribute value (rather than the type
// attribute) to identify the type of content to display
if ( nodeName === "object" ) {
    dest.outerHTML = src.outerHTML;
}
```

Not sure exactly what that means tbh

What do I need to change to stop it throwing an error, and why?

Comment: Looks like it may be the `wrapAll`, not the `.slice()`.

Comment: Have you tried a current version of jQuery? It could be a bug that's been fixed.

Comment: Please use a non-minified jQuery version for debugging jQuery errors

Comment: Wait... you're selecting `<li>` elements, but you're naming your variable `divs`? That's just confusing. But then you're trying to wrap groups of these `<li>` element in another `<li>`. That's just invalid HTML.

Comment: @user1689607: Absolutely right, I had invalid HTML. I have fixed it, and I still receive the error.

Comment: @Bergi Sure thing - have updated to jQuery 1.8.2 dev version, and will update main post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather obvious in retrospect - replace the `<object>` with `<div>` and it works fine.